# spring tool suite spring mvc project - 22 problems right after creating

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, eclipse-plugin

So, I downloaded and installed STS and then I've created a new Spring MVC Project. Right after that sts alert me about 22 problems, here they are:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Missing artifact aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0    pom.xml /ContactManager line 1          Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE   pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE   pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.slf4j:slf4j-api:pom:1.6.6 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:pom:1.6.6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): C:\Users\Skeeve\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.6.6\slf4j-api-1.6.6.pom.ahc3656264e3b414ddf (Не удается найти указанный файл)   pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.6 pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.10   pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE   pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE   pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE    pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE   pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE    pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE  pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact junit:junit:jar:4.7    pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2 pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1  pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5  pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1    pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15 pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
Missing artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.6  pom.xml /ContactManager line 1  Maven Dependency Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    ContactManager      Unknown Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Skeeve\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\3.1.1.RELEASE\spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar'   ContactManager      Build path  Build Path Problem
```

How can I solve that problem? Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've also encountered a lot of error when creating a new STS project for the first time.  This seems to be happen only if I don't have any Maven repository or haven't launch/use Maven before.  In my case, I solve this by launching Maven command from command line manually.  Try to 'cd' to the project directory that contains `pom.xml` and call `mvn` that comes with STS from there.

```
   cd c:\users\name\sts-projects\projectname
   c:\programs\springsource\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin\mvn compile
```

Then, open STS, right click on project name, select 'Maven', 'Update Project...' Select on 'Force Update of Snapshots/Releases'.  Don't select 'Offline'.

Comment: Works perfect for me, thank you very much! I also recommend everyone who meets the same problem to set enviromental variables, so they can just open project folder and run 'mvn compile'. Here is the link, for example: http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/developing/dev-environment/maven/maven-env-var.html

Comment: Ticking the "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" checkbox did it for me! Thanks

Comment: thanks..solved my issue.."ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar"

Answer (score 3):

Are you behind a proxy? If so, you need to configure Maven to use it.

If that is not the case just right-click on your project and select **Maven->Update Project Configuration**. This should work. Probably you have to clean/refresh the project.

Comment: clean/refresh added a new problem: 'Description Resource Path Location Type
Class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver' not found [config set: ContactManager/web-context] servlet-context.xml /ContactManager/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet line 19 Spring Beans Problem'

Comment: And I dont have Maven->Update Project Configuration, I have Maven->Update Project... option. Is it what you mean?

Comment: @OP in case you missed it -- proxy refers to internet proxy. Typically if you're using company's internet you would have some kind of proxy for security purposes. Have a look at http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies to setup your maven proxy configuration. This is needed so maven can lookup the missing artifact from central repository on the net

Comment: @Skeeze Yes, it is "Update Project". Just click on this, select your project, leave all settings as they are and your project should be working.

Comment: @gerrytan I've imported another project with maven and everything worked well. so, I guess that is not the case?

Comment: I just checked my version of STS and can't find a project type "Spring MVC Project". Did you import some sources (and which ones)?

Comment: File->New->Spring Template Project->Spring MVC Project

Comment: OK, see that. Now I did this and it works fine here. I'm sure it's a Maven problem. What you can try: Right-click on the project > Maven > Disable Maven project nature. Close the project. Close Eclipse. Open Eclipse, open the project and than right click on the project > Configure > Convert to Maven project.

Comment: Nope, still the same thing :( Maybe I should really check proxy configuration. But I have no idea, why everything that need internet connection is working without proxy config and maven is not. And I mean not only browser and skype. Marketplace and spring template downloading works fine.